# How does a Kafka Consumer keep track of processed messages if auto commit happen less often than poll?

Tags: apache-kafka, producer-consumer, redpanda

So if a Kafka Consumer has auto commit enabled with a commit interval of 5 sec, and we consume a batch every 1 second ...

... will the consumer process messages multiple times before the auto commit has been completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you marked the batch processed, it will commit to the partition in the cluster every 5 sec. The consumer issues the next batch poll to get the next set of messages, so it would start from the next offset. Unless there is a error occurred, it's not likely to get the same batch of msg again.

Comment: Thanks, so the consumer internally keeps track of what it has processed? It just askes for the next set based on what it just processed?

Comment: Offsets are cached in memory (for faster access). And yes, it will ask for the next set  from it's current marked process offset.